# Problema Reconocimiento de numeros provenientes de una Imagen

Tags: java, python, imagen, ocr

he estado intentando reconocer un numero serial en varias imágenes provenientes de fusiles como la siguiente:

[image: Numero Serial]

He intentado con un OCR para reconocimiento de imagen llamado Asprise: 
[Asprise OCR](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/java-ocr-api-overview.html)
y ha funcionado, sin embargo desarrolle el proyecto para llevarlo a cabo en una raspberry pi 3, y al correr este software me sale la siguiente excepción:

```
>>> UnsatisfiedLinkError occurs. To fix it, visit 
http://asprise.com/ocr/fix-link-error?os=Linux
Dependency information:     not a dynamic executable
java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/arm:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/jni:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib
OS: Linux 4.9.24-v7+ arm
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.24-v7+ #993 SMP Wed Apr 26 18:01:23 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

JVM: 1.7.0_121-b00 32bit by Oracle Corporation

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/libaocr.so: /tmp/libaocr.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory (Possible cause: can't load IA 32-bit .so on a ARM-bit platform)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1968)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1893)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1062)
    at com.asprise.ocr.util.OcrLibHelper.loadOcrLib(OcrLibHelper.java:50)
    at com.asprise.ocr.Ocr.<clinit>(Ocr.java:457)
    at mundo.ProcesadorImagen.<init>(ProcesadorImagen.java:7)
    at Interfaz.InterfazPrincipalArmamento.abrir(InterfazPrincipalArmamento.java:125)
    at Interfaz.BarraMenu.actionPerformed(BarraMenu.java:150)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:218)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:133)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:118)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)

>>> Relax, it's easy to fix: http://asprise.com/ocr/fix-link-error?os=Linux
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.asprise.ocr.Ocr.doSetup(Z)I
    at com.asprise.ocr.Ocr.doSetup(Native Method)
    at com.asprise.ocr.Ocr.setUp(Ocr.java:491)
    at mundo.ProcesadorImagen.<init>(ProcesadorImagen.java:10)
    at Interfaz.InterfazPrincipalArmamento.abrir(InterfazPrincipalArmamento.java:125)
    at Interfaz.BarraMenu.actionPerformed(BarraMenu.java:150)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3312)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:218)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:133)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:122)


at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:118)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Revise la ruta de la tmp y existe libaocr.so así que supongo que es porque no puede ejecutar algo basado en 32bits, lo único que se me ocurre es instalar **Exagear Desktop** y creo que funcionaria pero no estoy seguro y ademas generaría mas gastos.

Si alguien tiene otra idea comprobada por favor decirmela, he intentado mediante python y librerias como pytesseract y pillow pero nada me ha funcionado hasta ahora, acepto cualquier ayuda o sugerencia.

Comment: Por lo que ví en la pagina de [Aprise](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/python-ocr-for-windows-mac-linux-download.html) lo que ellos distribuyen son "binarios" para las tres plataformas principales, pero no para la raspberry.

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje se error claramente indica que estás usando una librería *linkeada* dinámicamente en una ruta que no existe en el sistema de archivos de la Raspberry.

Según el mismo mensaje, aconseja dirigirte a la página para obtener un nuevo binario con el cargador dinámico apuntando a la ruta correcta.

No estoy familiarizado con el ambiente Raspbian pero generalmente corregir las rutas en el archivo `ld.config` en el directorio donde residen las librerías dinámicas compartidas ( usualmente `/lib` o `/usr/lib/` ) para después ejecutar el comando `ldconfig` que ajusta las rutas internas en todas las librerías de acuerdo con `ld.config` podria ser suficiente

Alternativamente (eliminando complejidad, lo que es una ventaja en sistemas embebidos) si existe una **versión estática** de la librería, (tal vez ligeramente más grande, pero sin dependencias ni rutas ) yo recomendaría usar esa versión.